# DrawerToggle not working on some versions

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

On two devices with the Android Version `4.3` and `4.4.2` the `DrawerToggle` does not respond to clicks. On two other devices with the Version `4.1.2` and `5.0` it's clickable. My implementation looks like this:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

....

private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

....

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

addFragment(R.id.navigation_drawer_fragment_frame_layout, NavigationDrawerFragment.getInstance(drawerLayout));
drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

Comment: did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This implemenation worked for me

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this,  mDrawerLayout, mToolbar,
        R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close
    );
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```